# UISearchController search bar cannot be activated

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

The `UISearchBar` object and its `UISearchBarTextField` subview both return `NO` for `canBecomeFirstResponder`. Under what conditions would `UISearchController` prevent searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the view controller containing the search bar had not been considered “appeared.”